# Simple mySQL query failing

Tags: mysql

I have the following mySQL query, and for some reason I can't get it working.

I have two tables:

exp_competition_purchase_upload_total contains a member id and total_uploads column.
exp_channel_titles has lots of columns, but the two I need to check is author id and channel id.

My aim is to query the first table and locate any rows, find the member_id and take the upload_total associated with it. Then go to the second table, count the rows that have an author id that matches the member id from table one, and has a channel id of 1.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS uploads, c.upload_total 
FROM exp_competition_purchase_upload_total AS c
LEFT JOIN exp_channel_titles AS t ON c.member_id = t.author_id
WHERE c.member_id = '1'
AND t.channel_id = '1'
```

Currently the count is returning, but not the upload_total number. The following works:

```
SELECT upload_total 
FROM exp_competition_purchase_upload_total
WHERE member_id = '1'
```

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: There is a syntax error in your aggregation functions. Please check that./

Comment: `SUM(c.upload_total)`?

Comment: @PraveenKumar I can't see the error, can you point it out for me?

Comment: @JoopEggen Just tried this, thank you, but no luck.

Comment: have you tried changin `JOIN` types? like `INNER JOIN` ?

Comment: @Þaw Yes, with no luck.

Comment: could you try this and tell me what you get `SELECT SUM(upload_total) 
FROM exp_competition_purchase_upload_total
WHERE member_id = '1'`

Comment: Yes, it returns 10, which is the correct number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS uploads, 
  SUM(IFNULL(c.upload_total,0)) 
FROM 
  exp_competition_purchase_upload_total AS c
LEFT JOIN exp_channel_titles AS t 
  ON c.member_id = t.author_id
  AND t.channel_id = '1'
WHERE 
  c.member_id = '1'
```

Comment: what type is `upload_total` column ?

Comment: are you sure you have rows in `exp_competition_purchase_upload_total` table with `member_id = '1'`?